# containsObject - why doesen't this work?

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsnumber, nsindexpath

I have an array that I am trying to check wether or not an indexPath(.row) exists in.

I use this code:

```
if ([array containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]){
    NSLog(@"Yep, it exists in there.");
}
```

the array consist of the numbers 3, 8 and 2. The index path loads numbers fromm 0 to 8 in a loop.

Can anybody see why this doesen't work?

Comment: Please `CFShow(array);` and report the output.

Comment: <CFArray 0x5f64350 [0x2b020a0]>{type = immutable, count = 3, values = (
 0 : <CFString 0x5f63360 [0x2b020a0]>{contents = "3"}
 1 : <CFString 0x5f648e0 [0x2b020a0]>{contents = "8"}
 2 : <CFString 0x5f63bc0 [0x2b020a0]>{contents = "2"}

Comment: Oops - you have strings in there, not numbers...

Comment: Hahah, was it that stupid..? :P
Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the array contains strings, you should compare against strings. To create a numeric string, use `-stringWithFormat:`. So:

```
if ([array containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]]){
    NSLog(@"Yep, it exists in there.");
}
```

A better solution is to store NSNumber's in the array.

Comment: Yeah, I use that now. The array is loaded from a plist, so thats not possible (i think).

Comment: @Emil: It is possible. Choose "Number" in Types in the property list editor. Save as binary or XML format.

Comment: From @PaNaVTEC: I Think the answer of "A better solution is to store NSNumber's in the array." + Jim answer is the correct way